# Perl 6 error message: Malformed UTF-8 in block <unit>

Tags: raku

I'm trying to read a downloaded html-file

```perl6
my $file = "sn.html";
my $in_fh = open $file, :r;
my $text = $in_fh.slurp;
```

and I get the following error message:

```perl6
Malformed UTF-8
  in block <unit> at prog.p6 line 10
```

How to avoid this and get access to the file's contents?

Comment: If the file does not contain UTF-8 and you do not know its encoding, you could try read the file as binary using the [`read`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::Handle.html#method_read) method. On the other hand, if you know the encoding of the file, for example `latin1`, you could try pass the encoding to `open` using its `:enc` flag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you do not specify an encoding when opening a file, it will assume `utf8`.  Apparently, the file that you wish to open, contains bytes that cannot be interpreted as UTF-8.  Hence the error message.

Depending on what you want to do with the file contents, you could either set the `:bin` named parameter, to have the file opened in binary mode.  Or you could use the special `utf8-c8` encoding, which will assume UTF-8 until it encounters bytes it cannot encode: in that case it will generate temporary code points.

See https://docs.raku.org/language/unicode#UTF8-C8 for more information.

Answer (score 4):

For slurp, if you have some idea about encoding, you can also add encoding specifically.

From documentation (`https://docs.perl6.org/routine/slurp`):

```
my $text_contents   = slurp "path/to/file", enc => "latin1";
```

I used it today for a stupid file encoded in ISO-8859-1.