# perl6 Malformed UTF-8 causes program crash

Tags: utf-8, raku, malformed

I am trying to download a webpage; then analyze it with regex; then get the files discovered by the regex. I have 2 questions:

(1) I use `wget` to download the webpages and files, using this line

```
my $webPage = "onePage";
my $result = run <<wget -O $webPage $aSite>>, :out, :err;
```

where `$webPage` is the output file from `wget`. Question: Any perl6 equivalent to wget? I used module `URI::FetchFile` from perl6 website; it gets some files, but it cannot get webpages.

(2) The $webPage downloaded by wget sometimes has malformed UTF-8 characters what caused my program to crash. When I do

```
cat onePage
```

from the shell, those malformed UTF-8 characters shows up as a blob, and this command causes the same error as my program:

```
cat onePage | perl6 -ne '.say;'
```

and the error output from perl6 is

```
Malformed UTF-8
  in block <unit> at -e line 1
```

and on the terminal or shell, one of the malformed UTF-8 char shows as a blob like this:

```
h�lt
```

and if I try to remove non-print chars, then the result is that I miss a huge number of links to files:

```
$tmpLine ~~ s/<-[print]>//; # this causes my program to miss many files
```

How do I best handle these malformed UTF-8 chars or any malformed unicodes or even malformed control chars ?

Comment: See also [Perl 6 error message: Malformed UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49320061/1077672).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any perl6 equivalent to wget?

There are several. [`HTTP::Agent`](https://github.com/sergot/http-useragent) is now considered the more up-to-date, but you can also use [`LWP::Simple`](https://github.com/perl6/perl6-lwp-simple).

> How do I best handle these malformed UTF-8 chars or any malformed unicodes or even malformed control chars ?

You might want to try [`UTF8-C8`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/unicode#UTF8-C8) encoding. But it's probably not a problem if you obtain directly the page from the perl6 program.

Crashes, however, are a completely different thing. The best is to create a [Rakudo issue](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo)

Comment: "Crashes, however, are a completely different thing. The best is to create a Rakudo issue". I'm pretty sure lisprogtor just meant a fatal run-time error, one that correctly pinpoints the problem. lisprogtor am I right about what you meant by crash? And, assuming you've tried the suggestions, do you still think it makes sense for you to file a bug report?

Comment: Hi jjmerelo and raiph, thank you very much for your help. I ended up using shell( "iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c $webPage > $cleanPage" ) to removed those malformed UTF-8 chars and my program ran smoothly. I hope there is perl6 function to do that. I will try remove control-chars from perl6 as malformed chars kind of look like control chars anyway.

Comment: Back to the issue of crash, if you pass a binary string to perl6, then the program exits. Try: cat /usr/bin/zip | perl6 -ne '.say;' and try cat /usr/bin/zip | perl6 -ne 'if /foo/ {.say;}'; both will terminate with the same error message " Malformed UTF-8 in block <unit> at -e line 1" I am not sure perl6 is supposed to be this way or not. But if the string doesn't contain "foo", then it should just not match instead of reporting error and terminate. Right?

Comment: Okay, I cannot use removing control-chars as a way to remove malformed UTF-8 chars. Seems like perl6 has to interpret the char first before it is classified as control-chars or as other chars. This code causes the same error: cat /usr/bin/zip | perl6 -ne 's:g/<cntrl>/_/; .say;'; and the error output is the same: "Malformed UTF-8 in block <unit> at -e line 1"